# Long listing showing hours since modification

Tags: ls, date

Is there an option (preferably a GNU and/or FreeBSD option) that instructs `ls` to display modification time, not in absolute date time, but instead showing a number indicating hours (or days) since modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to get `ls` to do what you want.  Depending on what you're looking for, you could build a script that exhibits that behavior.

It would be a *lot* of work to get all the bells an whistles that `ls` has in addition to this behavior, but you could get *just* this behavior pretty easily.

Here's a quick example of such a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function age() {
    local -r last_modification="${1}"
    local -r now="$(date +%s)"

    local -r seconds="$((now - last_modification))"
    if [[ ${seconds} -lt 60 ]]; then
        printf "%s seconds ago" "${seconds}"
        return
    fi

    local -r minutes="$((seconds / 60))"
    if [[ ${minutes} -lt 60 ]]; then
        printf "%s minutes ago" "${minutes}"
        return
    fi

    local -r hours="$((minutes / 60))"
    if [[ ${hours} -lt 24 ]]; then
        printf "%s hours ago" "${hours}"
        return
    fi

    local -r days="$((hours / 24))"
    if [[ ${days} -lt 365 ]]; then
        printf "%s days ago" "${days}"
        return
    fi

    local -r years="$((days / 365))"
    printf "%s years ago" "${years}"
}

function list_file() {
    local -r target_file="${1}"
    local -r last_modification="$(stat --format=%Y "${target_file}")"

    stat --format="%A %2h %-8U %-8G %5s $(printf "%-14s" "$(age "${last_modification}")") %n" "${target_file}"
}

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    for i in * .*; do
        list_file "${i}"
    done
else
    for i; do
        list_file "${i}"
    done
fi
```

Here's a sample run:

```
$ myls
-rw-------  1 user  group   9061 3 days ago     .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group    127 2 years ago    .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group    611 1 years ago    .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  group   4096 155 days ago   .cache
-rw-------  1 user  group  40583 5 hours ago    .histfile
-rw-------  1 user  group    703 1 minutes ago  .lesshst
...
$

$ myls myls
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  group   1127 2 minutes ago  myls
$
```

If you give the script parameters, then it will list those parameters, otherwise it will list the content of the current directory.

It uses `stat` to get the traditional fields that `ls` presents.  Instead of showing the date, it uses the `age` function to print a "friendly, x units of time ago" string.  That function could be enhanced, depending on what specifically you want to see.